# How to allocate a task to each processor core?

Tags: java, android, encryption, multicore

I am performing basic encryption/decryption on a Quad core android phone.

Currently encryption time is 1.45 second per file. For 200 files thats around 5 minutes.
I could improve 4 times in performance if I used all 4 cores.

```
for(i=0;i<200;i++)
{
     encrypt(file[i]);
}
```

would be a simplified pseudocode, I am using now.

How can I call the encrypt function parallely on all 4 processor cores in android java programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **ExecutorService** to perform tasks in parallel: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Something like this:

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CORE_COUNT);
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                encrypt(file[i]);
            }
        });
    }

    // Waiting for completion
    while (!executorService.awaitTermination(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: Wonderfully written answer ! , However From analysis, I have seen that the file renaming (after encryption) consumes most time. Would this method rename parallely or will the Android File manager only allow ExecutorService to run 1 after the other for renaming purpose?

Comment: It depends on many things. If target partition the same, than renaming will be fast (but environment will check you permissions for file renaming and this moment can slow down application performance), but if partitions are not the same, than it depends on file size, because it will copy whole file to new partition.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `ExecutorService` (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). In your loop, wrap each call to encrypt in a Runnable or Callable and collect the Future's in a list. Then iterate over the futures to wait until they have all finished and handle the results.